# Windows Phone 8 - Error while Serializing/Deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a Class A and Class B that contains List of class A objects.

```
public class Item
{
    public string X{ get; set; }
    public string Y{ get; set; }
}
public class ItemCollection
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    //Some methods
}
```

I can serialize it by:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream ifs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myxml.xml", FileMode.Create, isfile);
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(itemlist.items.GetType());
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ifs);
ser.WriteObject(writer, itemlist.items);
```

But while deserializing it, I get "... Root element is missing." error.

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream ifs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myxml.xml", FileMode.Open, isfile);
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(itemlist.Items.GetType());
XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(ifs);
itemlist.items= (List<Item>)ser.ReadObject(reader);
```

Is there any other/better way of serializing/deserializing one class that contains list/collection of another class?

Comment: Well, what are the actual file contents? *is* the root element missing? Is this perhaps related to the number of things you haven't disposed / closed properly? Did you try adding `reader.MoveToContent()` ?

Comment: I am writing the List of items and reading them (file is overwritten). I am getting "Root element is missing." with reader.MoveToContent() also.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the problem is simply that you are **wiping** the file when you open it to deserialize, via `FileMode.Create`. So *of course* the root element is missing: *it is empty*. You probably have the `FileMode.Create` and `FileMode.Open` inverted between the serialize/deserialize. And then add a few `using` for good measure.

The *serialize* should use `FileMode.Create`, to truncate or create the file fresh for new data.

The *deserialize* should use `FileMode.Open`, to look at the existing data.

Comment: Sorry, that was copy-paste error. In actual code, FileMode is Open while deserializing and Create while serializing. I corrected it in the question.

Comment: @aaa again: what are the file contents?

Comment: I am serializing Itemcollection class. Serializing is completing successfully. But while deserializing, I am getting the error. So I don't know what the file contains. How can I check the file contents?

Comment: @aaa just open the file after writing it, using any text-based reader API, and dump the contents